# Can the approach of conditional probability be used for mutually exclusive events?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

### A problem in probability goes like:

If you have, say three similar cups, one of which holds a marble (the cups are opaque and inverted so you can't see the inside of the cups), the probability of finding the marble in any one of them is 1/3. Name the cups A, B, and C for convenience. Now if you were asked to choose the cup that holds the marble and you seemingly choose B, but then you are told that the marble is not in A, then if you're asked to keep your choice or switch to C. It is known that switching, certainly is a better option, because the odds of finding the marble in C are 2/3 while in A, they are 0, and 1/3 in B.
Which can be proved using the fact that,  $\mathsf P(B)+(P(A)+P(C))=1.$

---

Can this be proved using conditional probability?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is basically the Monty-Hall problem. Whether it is good to switch depends on the concrete rules. To see this , imagine you get the information that the marble is not in a particular cup ONLY if you chose the cup with the marble (otherwise you do not get the option). In this case switching is "fatal" (you never get the marble!).

Comment: Under the usual rules of the Monty-Hall problem switching actually brings a 2/3-chance , but not with the argument $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1$ because those probabilities are all 1/3 (they are not conditioned). The reason that switching brings 2/3 is that you only fail to get the marble , if you chose the cup with the marble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_m, B_m$ and $C_m$ be the events that the marble is in cups $A, B$ and $C$ respectively; also let $A_r$ be the event that cup $A$ is revealed, i.e. shown not to contain the marble.

Suppose you choose cup $B$, and are then shown that the marble is not in cup $A$. Then the probability of winning by keeping cup $B$ is

$$\begin{align}
P(B_m | A_r) &= \frac{P(B_m \cap A_r)}{P(A_r)} \\[2mm]
&= \frac{P(A_r | B_m) \cdot P(B_m)}{P(A_r | A_m) \cdot P(A_m) + P(A_r | B_m) \cdot P(B_m) + P(A_r | C_m) \cdot P(C_m)} \\[2mm]
&= \frac{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)}{\left( 0 \right) \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) + \left( 1 \right) \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)} \\[2mm]
&= \frac{1}{3}
\end{align}$$

Similarly, the probability of winning by switching to cup $C$ is

$$\begin{align}
P(C_m | A_r) &= \frac{P(C_m \cap A_r)}{P(A_r)} \\[2mm]
&= \frac{P(A_r | C_m) \cdot P(C_m)}{P(A_r | A_m) \cdot P(A_m) + P(A_r | B_m) \cdot P(B_m) + P(A_r | C_m) \cdot P(C_m)} \\[2mm]
&= \frac{\left( 1 \right) \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)}{\left( 0 \right) \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) + \left( 1 \right) \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)} \\[2mm]
&= \frac{2}{3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for, the approach you used is pure and quite intuitive to me as a student. Thanks.